# Bruteforce protector class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to protect the password login for a website against automated guessing. After too many failed attempts from an IP address, it presents a mandatory CAPTCHA test to the user.

The class is supposed to not forgive the source completely after a successful login attempt, and the more failed attempts the more penalties.

Are there any logic or lock fails here?

```
public class BruteforceProtector
{
    const int max_log_per_source = 20;
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, LinkedList<DateTimeOffset>> requests;

    public BruteforceProtector()
    {
        requests = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, LinkedList<DateTimeOffset>>();
    }

    public bool isBlocked(string source, int limit)
    {
        LinkedList<DateTimeOffset> list;
        var haslist = requests.TryGetValue(source, out list);

        if (!haslist)
            return false;

        lock (list)
        {
            removeOld(list);

            return list.Count > limit;
        }
    }

    public void ForgiveSource(string source)
    {
        LinkedList<DateTimeOffset> list;
        if (!requests.TryGetValue(source, out list))
            return;

        lock (list)
        {
            if (list.Count > 0)
                list.RemoveLast();
        }
    }

    public void HandleRequest(string source, int limit, out bool blocked)
    {
        blocked = true;
        bool haslist = true;

        var list = requests.GetOrAdd(source, (x) =>
        {
            var newlist = new LinkedList<DateTimeOffset>();
            newlist.AddLast(DateTimeOffset.Now);
            haslist = false;
            return newlist;
        });

        if (!haslist)
        {
            blocked = false;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            lock (list)
            {
                list.AddLast(DateTimeOffset.Now);

                removeOld(list);

                if (list.Count > max_log_per_source)
                    list.RemoveFirst();

                blocked = list.Count > limit;
            }
        }
    }

    private void removeOld(LinkedList<DateTimeOffset> list)
    {
        if (list.Count < 1)
            return;

        var oldest = list.First.Value;
        while (oldest.AddHours(list.Count) < DateTimeOffset.Now)
        {
            list.RemoveFirst();

            if (list.Count > 0)
                oldest = list.First.Value;
            else
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with very minor *issues*.

Usually underscore isn't used in C# names, PascalCase and camelCase are usually preferred (see `max_log_per_source`). Functions are usually PascalCase (then, for example, `isBlocked` should be `IsBlocked`).

Private fields (like `requests`) do not need any special prefix but you'd better (for clarity) to use a prefix (for example `_`) or access them like `this.requests`.

I do not see any extension point in your class then it should be marker `sealed`.

Fields you initialize only in ctor and that aren't supposed to be changed should be marked readonly: `private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, LinkedList<DateTimeOffset>> requests;`.

---

In `isBlocked()` you do not really need `haslist` local variable. It may be simplified to (you're already doing this in `ForgiveSource()`):

```
LinkedList<DateTimeOffset> list;
if (!requests.TryGetValue(source, out list))
    return false;
```

If you're using C# 7 code might be further simplified:

```
if (!requests.TryGetValue(source, out var list))
    return false;
```

---

`ForgiveSource()` and `HandleRequest()` seem to work in concert however I'd change calling logic to avoid to add an entry when login is valid.

---

This code:

```
if (condition) {
    // Something
    return;
} else {
    // Something else
}
```

Can be simplified, you don't need an `else` here:

```
if (condition) {
    // Something
    return;
}

// Something else
```

---

I find that usually `list.Count == 0` is much much clearer than `list.Count < 1`.

---

To me a type declared as `ConcurrentDictionary<string, LinkedList<DateTimeOffset>>` is a missing opportunity to introduce a separate specialized class. More than that you have a thread-safe `ConcurrentDictionary` and an inner `LinkedList` which is not. Why don't you introduce a `MultiMap<string, DateTimeOffset>` type? It's a pretty common data structure to reuse. Also you may wrap it (or extend it) into your own `LogInAttemptsCollection` (which will be thread-safe). In this way you might **separate logic** ("list logic" from "is blocked" logic)

---

Is `limit` a *dynamic* parameter which will change for each request? If not then you may consider to move it to a property (or to a `readonly` field set in ctor).

---

Why `HandleRequest()` has an `out` parameter and a void return type? `out` parameters should be avoided, when possible, and in this case you just need to change return type to `bool`.

---

One note: I *feel* `removeOld()` algorithm is way too *complex* (in general, not for its implementation). Is any reasoning behind this?

Comment: `list.Count == 0` vs `list.Count < 1` - can't you be in debt and owe a list a few items? Its count would be negative then ;-)

Comment: Oh, I thought in that case we may use a `Promise<T>` to keep track of our debt! ;)

Comment: Thank you for reviewing. Limit is not dynamic, my thought was that different callers could have different limits (in afterthought this could be very bad if limit is higher than maxLogPerSource. After some thinking; maybe check limit every time and increase maxLogPerSource?). My reasoning for the out variable in HandleRequest is that the function name doesn't really convey what it returns (imo). About removeOld(): It's to make the penalty exponential(?), so you couldn't do 'limit' attempts every hour for the next 5 years, but also be gentle on sources doing making a couple of mistakes.

Comment: Should i edit the question adding another code block with your improvements?

Comment: You might add the question with clarifications you wrote in your comment but when you  have a different/improved version of your code you should add a new question (linking back to this one to keep track of changes).

Comment: 1) Hmmm same instance shares different limits for different callers? Nothing wrong with it (just add proper checking) if you have a true use-case for that. 2) Agree that name is then wrong but then you just need to change function name! 3) Just asking but isn't then easier a _temporary_ ban?  1st ban for 1 hour, 2nd for 2 hours, 3rd for 4 hours and so on...in this way (isn't it similar to SO bans?!) you just need to keep track of latest N relevant bans/attempts

Comment: 3) I don't fully understand what oldest.AddHours(list.Count) does myself (LOL), but I know that it's really harsh on someone making many failed attempts and be solving captchas for the next days or something.

Comment: 3) I also want to reset the ban timer as time passes...

Comment: 3) Let's say you keep at most (and only) 5 failed attempts in the queue. Ban time is exponential (calculated from latest attempt, which obviously renew/reset the counter). List is a simple fixed size queue (push new failed attempt -> pushes out older failed attempt). You may "grace" one old failed attempt for each successful attempt. well, anyay...I'm going pretty off-topic! ;)